# Flutter: Detect new day in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I detect a new day change in flutter firestore. I want to run a function whenever it detects that a new day past. For instance a function that works whenever it becomes 12 AM the next day.

11:59 PM

[image]

12:00 AM

[image]

I have written a function to move all the values down one step, but how do I run this function whenever it become 12 AM, or when a new day begins.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a perfect fit for the [Firebase Sheduled Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). With those you can create a trigger that runs every day at 12 AM and run your code inside:

```js
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every day at 12 AM').onRun((context) => {
  // write your code here
  return null;
});
```